# Flutter release apk wipe data

Tags: android, flutter, apk

I'm developing local android app using flutter. App installs directly on device from "app-release.apk". When I installing next release, previous installation fully erased (shared preferences, sqlite database, etc). Is there any way to keep the data?

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't erase the data by default, I think you are having problems in signing the application with a release key. So you are basically uninstalling the previous application and installing a new one instead of installing the new app on the top of the old one.

Please go through this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) for building android release applications

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling Android auto-backup and see if this problem persists.

I thought I had this problem, but it turned out that the last Android auto-backup that saved was from when the SharedPreferences and database were empty. So every time I installed an update it would restore this same empty backup.